# infrared sensor

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone can tell me the meanings of the fields of *IrMsg.msg*
(http://svn.code.sf.net/p/roscorobot/code/trunk/Electric/Corobot/corobot_msgs/msg/IrMsg.msg)?

```
float32 voltage1
float32 voltage2
float32 range1
float32 range2
```

Why there are two ranges and two voltages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54171/infrared-sensor/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't written the message, so without any further information my guess is that there are two sensors.

voltage is probably provided as the mapping from voltage to range is usually not unique for IRs.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1